# How to set the title for the first column of DataGridView (RowHeaders column) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, vb.net-2010

How to give title in RowHeaders datagridview in VB.NET?

by that I mean circled the color in yellow in the screenshot below.

note : I use vb.net 2010
[image: RowHeaders datagridview]
Thanks
roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a property [TopLeftHeaderCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.topleftheadercell?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for that cell. You can use it and set the `Value` for the cell:

```
DataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "Index"
```

[image]

You can also set the other properties of the cell, like its alignment, for example:

```
DataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
```

Comment: Thanks. It went perfectly and can I set alignment "TopLeftHeaderCell.Value="Index"?

Comment: @roy, yes you can set alignment or other properties of the cell like any other cell. I the example for setting alignment. See the bottom of the answer.

Comment: It's going perfectly and you're indeed my master and teacher.I have another post maybe you can help "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491388/how-to-color-formborder-in-vb-net"

Comment: one more how to give a notification comment to your name because I tried not to succeed

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped! You can notify people by putting @ behind their name and usually the comment box shows an auto-complete context menu to choose the name. But when you comment under one of my posts, you do not necessarily need to notify me, I get the notification because it's my post. Also you cannot notify me in a thread that I'm not in, for example in a different question or answer that I've not done anything with that.