# How to filter datagridview with combobbox without query and with invisible column in vb.net

Tags: winforms, datagridview, vb.net-2010, datagridviewcombobox

How to filter datagridview with combobbox without query and with invisible column in vb.net?
and is it possible to be only distinct or unique value?
I want filter in "SHI" column.
Note : I use visual studio 2010
Thanks
roy

```
Private Sub DataGridView()

        Try
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim query = "select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS,PRSOBBRT,PRSOBNET,SHI,FILENAME1,FILENAME2,FILENAME3,FILENAME4,FILENAME5,FILENAME6 FROM IFG WHERE QOH > 0"
Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
 Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        adapter.Fill(dt)
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
For x As Integer = 7 To 12
                Me.DataGridView1.Columns(x).Visible = False
            Next
Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            'cn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Since you are using a DataTable as data source of your DataGridView, then it's enough to assign the correct filter to `CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = ....`. To learn about filter syntax, take a look at [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-6.0). For example if column A is string, then `String.Format("A LIKE('{0}%')", TextBox1.Text)` if a filter that return the rows which their column A starts with the specified text of TextBox1.

Comment: You can also take a look at [RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-6.0) property to learn more. There are a lot of examples in stackoverflow for this case. Give some of them a try and if you encountered an issue, then ask a specific question about the specific issue.

Comment: @RezaAghaei , I want to use combobox filter. 
if I use a combobox with a query it makes the datagridview slow because the query is 2 times and also I have binding to the picturebox via the filename in the datagridview. 
maybe you can help me?

Comment: The filter will be applied to the data table. The comboBox, will be just the control that provides the filer value. For example you can handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the ComboBox and then set the desired filter for the DataTable. Please try something and come back with a specific question if you encountered an issue that you could not solve yourself.

Comment: @RezaAghaei , 'Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged'

Comment: @RezaAghaei , ' TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("SHI  LIKE '%{0}%'", ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString())'

Comment: @RezaAghaei , still not working maybe you can help me, give an answer from what I posted?