# How to change the color of titlebar in WinFroms application in .net core C#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, windows-forms-designer

I want to change the colour of my title-bar but I don't know how?
I am new to WinForms.

[image: Find the image here]

I tried to find the property in properties tab of the form that change the colour of title-bar but I don't know if such a property exist or not.

Comment: That's a window border that is part of the OS theme(you may consider it as not part of your form your form/app is just the inside). If you want something else then you need to remove the border of your Form and paint everything you want instead yourself.

Comment: @Ralf Thanks for clearing my doubts.

Comment: It's not a trivial thing to do. It involves handling native windows messages like WM_NCPAINT and calling native windows API function, and painting the titlebar and handling different situations yourself. It probably will be easier if you use a borderless form, and the show a custom titlebar yourself. As an idea for a custom titlebar, you can use a MenuStrip. Look at this working [example in VB.NET: Custom Titlebar using ManuStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70501390/3110834).